# Issue with script being triggered by wrong checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to enable/disable a place order button based on whether or not the terms acceptance checkbox has been checked. The script I have been working on works fine for that, but it's also triggered when a different checkbox (with a different id) is checked. Although the other checkbox enables the button, it doesn't disable it again when un-checking it. So I think it's something wrong with the 'on change' part.

I've tried everything I could find and can't make it work only when the checkbox with id 'terms' is checked:

```
<script>
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#payment #place_order').attr("disabled","disabled");
        },1000);            
    });
     jQuery(document).on('change','#terms',function() {
     var ischecked = document.getElementById("terms");
        if(ischecked.checked == false){
          jQuery('#payment #place_order').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }else{
            jQuery('#payment #place_order').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

The terms checkbox is as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox ios-switch" name="terms" id="terms">
```

And the other one that triggers it is as below:

```
<input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" id="createaccount" type="checkbox" name="createaccount" value="1">
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant HTML and CSS - what is `#payment #place_order`

Comment: Also you have jQuery so use it: `$(document).on('change','#terms',function() {
     var ischecked = this.checked; 
        if(!ischecked) {`

Comment: Also why a timeout?

Comment: @mplungjan I can't use `$` as it says not a recognised function, and the timeout is so the script runs last as I don't have access to re-order the other scripts which interrupt/cause issues if they run after this. I'm using a site plugin to insert scripts into the footer

Comment: If you insert the script into the footer, it is likely running last

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not clear.

Assuming the place order has the id of #place_order, there is no need to add the container

```js
jQuery(function() { // on page load
  jQuery('#place_order').attr("disabled", "disabled");

  jQuery(document).on("change", "#terms", function() { // assuming the terms is dynamically inserted
    if (!this.checked) {
      jQuery('#place_order').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
      jQuery('#place_order').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Terms <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox ios-switch" name="terms" id="terms"><br/>

<button id="place_order">Place order</button>

<hr/>

Create account <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" id="createaccount" type="checkbox" name="createaccount" value="1">
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work, the button is not disabled by default or change on clicking the box. However even if I replace the timeout part it still doesn't seem to do anything (although no console errors).

Comment: I cannot help you without seeing the HTML. If the terms are inserted, you DO need to delegate so I will put that back

Comment: Thanks, I added the html for the checkboxes from your earlier comment

Comment: The script works. There must be another script on the page that uses the class to check more than one checkbox. You need to look at the class names